# Judging the form being rendered

Tags: python, django

I have a modal here through which user can login/signup.Now that through Jquery and Ajax I am able to change forms on clicking the respective links but in landing view only 1 function is working(either login or signup). I want to judge whether UserLoginForm is being rendered or UserRegisterForm so that in landing view I can render the respective functionality.
I am new to Django so I don't know what I am saying is possible or not but if anyone can guide  me in the right direction that would be great.
Thanks!!

```
    <!-- Login Modal-->

    <div class="modal fade" id="LoginModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">

            <h5 class="modal-title" >DearDiary</h5>

          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">

<div class="container">
    <div class="omb_login">
        <h3 class="omb_authTitle"><span class='log-in'>Login</span> or <span class='sign-up'><a href="#" class='signup'>Sign up</a></span></h3>

        <div class="row   omb_socialButtons">
            <div class="col-xs-4  col-sm-12">
                <a href="{% url 'social:begin' 'facebook' %}" class="btn btn-lg btn-block omb_btn-facebook">
                    <i class="fa fa-facebook visible-xs"></i>
                    <span class="hidden-xs">Facebook</span>
                </a>
            </div>
            <!--  <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-2">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-block omb_btn-twitter">
                    <i class="fa fa-twitter visible-xs"></i>
                    <span class="hidden-xs">Twitter</span>
                </a>
            </div>  
            <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-2">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-block omb_btn-google">
                    <i class="fa fa-google-plus visible-xs"></i>
                    <span class="hidden-xs">Google+</span>
                </a>
            </div> -->
        </div>

        <div class="row  omb_loginOr">
            <div class="col-xs-12  col-sm-12">
                <hr class="omb_hrOr">
                <span class="omb_spanOr">or</span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row  ">
            <div class="col-xs-12  col-sm-12">  
                <form class="omb_loginForm" action="?" autocomplete="on" method="POST">
                  {% csrf_token %}
                  {{ form|crispy }}
                  <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" id='sign_in'>{{ title }}</button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Views.py:

```
def landing(request):
if request.method == 'POST': #How to judge the form here??
    form=UserLoginForm(request.POST or None)
    title='Sign In'
    if form.is_valid():
        username=form.cleaned_data.get('username')
        password=form.cleaned_data.get('password')
        user=authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        login(request,user)
      # print (request.user.is_authenticated())
        return redirect("/index")

else:
    title="Register"
    form=UserRegisterForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        user=form.save(commit=False)
        password=form.cleaned_data.get("password")
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        new_user = authenticate(username=user.username, password=password)
        login(request, new_user)
return render(request, "landing.html", {'form': form, 'title': title})
```

ajax to change forms:

```
    $(document).on('click', '.omb_authTitle .signup', function(e){
        // e.preventDefault();


    //Ajax
    $.ajax

       ({
           url:'/register',
           success:function(data)
           {
               var jq=jQuery(data);
               var title = jq.find(".omb_loginForm"); 
               $(document).find('.omb_loginForm').replaceWith(title);
                if ( $('.signup').is( "a" ) ) {
                $('.signup').contents().unwrap();
                $('.log-in').wrap( "<a href='#' class='login'></a>" );
              } else {
                  $('.signup').wrap( "<a></a>" );
              }


           } //Success function ends.

       }); //Ajax ends.


});


$(document).on('click', '.omb_authTitle .login', function(e){
    //alert('log-in');
    e.preventDefault();

 //Ajax
$.ajax

       ({
           url:'/login',
           success:function(data)
           {
               var jq=jQuery(data);
               var title = jq.find(".omb_loginForm"); 
               $(document).find('.omb_loginForm').replaceWith(title);
                if ( $('.login').is( "a" ) ) {
                $('.login').contents().unwrap();
                $('.sign-up').wrap( "<a href='#' class='signup'></a>" );
              } else {
                  //$('.login').wrap( "<a></a>" );
              }

           } //Success function ends.

       }); //Ajax ends.

});
```

Comment: It's a good approach to separate the functionality to login and register. write two views & urls for register and login

Comment: That I have done and /login and / register are working fine, but bootstrap modal doesn't have any specific URL so, and moreover I have implemented the forms through AJAX but confused about how to use login functionality for login form and signup functionality  for signup form?